# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch - many-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

my model struct is:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :traders
  has_many :service_locations
  has_many :services, through: :service_locations
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :service_locations
    has_many :locations, through: :service_locations
end

class ServiceLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :location
    belongs_to :service
end
```

I get the below error when i perform

```
s=Service.find(1)
l=Location.find(1)

s.service_locations << l

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: ServiceLocation(#84843750) expected, got Location(#93937750)
```

This also happens when the variables are reversed and I am having trouble identifying the problem here, any thoughts?

Comment: From the error it is clear as a crystal, in the `service_locations` you are trying to insert object `l` of class `Service`, You can see your mistake, right??

Comment: Sorry thats the letter l not the number 1, is that what you meant?

Comment: yes, I meant letter l, from your code: `s.service_locations << l`

Comment: Sorry, copied my code wrong, even updated correctly(edited post) I still get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code will be one of the following:

```
l=Location.find(1)    
s.locations << l
```

or

```
l=ServiceLocation.find(1)    
s.service_locations << l
```

This is self explanatory, I hope you got the error. Also have a look at the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), which will help you understand ActiveRecord Associations.